# Automatic derivation of ToJSON for (Map NewtypeOfText v)

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have a [Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html#t:Map) where the key is a newtype of Text. I would like to automatically (as much as possible) derive [ToJSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:ToJSON) and [FromJSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON) for this Map. [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2) already has instances for ToJSON and FromJSON for Map Text v.

My verbose code that works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric    #-}

module Test where

import           ClassyPrelude

import           Data.Aeson                  
import           GHC.Generics                (Generic)

import qualified Data.Map                    as M

newtype MyText = MyText {unMyText::Text} deriving (Eq, Ord)

data Bar = Bar deriving (Generic)
instance ToJSON Bar
instance FromJSON Bar

data Foo = Foo (Map MyText Bar)

instance ToJSON Foo where
  toJSON (Foo x) = toJSON mp
    where mp = M.fromList . map (\(x,y) -> (unMyText x,y)) . M.toList $ x

instance FromJSON Foo where
  parseJSON v = convert <$> parseJSON v
    where convert :: Map Text Bar -> Foo
          convert =  Foo . mapFromList . map (\(x,y) -> (MyText x,y)) . mapToList
```

Can I do something more like the following?

```
data Foo = Foo (Map MyText Bar) deriving (Generic)

instance ToJSON Foo 
instance FromJSON Foo
```

### Edit

I tried (but still no luck):

```
newtype MyText = MyText {unMyText::Text} deriving (Eq, Ord, ToJSON, FromJSON)
instance ToJSON Foo where
  toJSON (Foo x) = toJSON x
```

and

```
newtype MyText = MyText {unMyText::Text} deriving (Eq, Ord, ToJSON, FromJSON)
instance ToJSON Foo
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that you can't automatically derive this instance is 100% correct behavior. The reason that what you expect doesn't work is that there is no way to know that the instance `FromJSON (Map Text v)` can be used on values of type `Map MyText v`. This is because the creation and manipulation of a `Map` is predicated on the `Ord` instance of its key, and there is no way (for the compiler) to know that for all x y `(x == y) == (MyText x == MyText y)`, which is required to safely coerce `Map Text v` to `Map MyText v`. More technically, the *role declaration* of `Map` is:

```
type role Map nominal representational
```

Essentially this says that `Map k v` is only coercible to other maps whose first type parameter is identical. The wiki says:

> we have instance Coercible a b => Coercible (T a) (T b) if and only if
>   the first parameter has a representational role.

The class `Coercible` is used to do type safe coercions in recent versions of GHC (7.8?) 
For more information about *type roles* and their role in type safety, see [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Roles). The

If you plan to derive the instance for `Ord MyText`, then it is indeed safe to coerce `Map Text v` to `Map MyText v`, since the `Ord` instance is the same. This requires the use of `unsafeCoerce`. You still have to write the instance yourself, though:

```
instance ToJSON v => ToJSON (Map MyText v) where
  toJSON = toJSON . (unsafeCoerce :: Map MyText v -> Map Text v)

instance FromJSON v => FromJSON (Map MyText v) where 
  parseJSON = (unsafeCoerce :: Parser (Map Text v) -> Parser (Map MyText v)) . parseJSON
```

If you plan to write your own `Ord` instance, the above is absolutely not safe. Your solution is correct, but not very efficient. Use the following:

```
  toJSON = toJSON . M.mapKeys (coerce :: MyText -> Text)
  parseJSON = fmap (M.mapKeys (coerce :: Text -> MyText)) . parseJSON
```

Depending on your Ord instance, you may be able to use `mapKeysMonotonic` instead, which would be more efficient. See the documentation of `Data.Map` for precisely when you can use `mapKeysMonotonic`.

Then, the obvious things will work:

```
data Bar = Bar deriving (Eq, Ord, Generic)
instance ToJSON Bar
instance FromJSON Bar

data Foo = Foo (Map MyText Bar) deriving (Generic)
instance ToJSON Foo 
instance FromJSON Foo

-- Using GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
newtype Foo2 = Foo2 (Map MyText Bar) deriving (FromJSON, ToJSON)
```

Full code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, FlexibleInstances #-}

module Test where

import Data.Aeson                  
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)
import Data.Text (Text)
import GHC.Prim (coerce)
import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)

newtype MyText = MyText {unMyText::Text} deriving (Eq, Ord, Generic, ToJSON, FromJSON)

instance ToJSON v => ToJSON (Map MyText v) where
  -- toJSON = toJSON . M.mapKeys (coerce :: MyText -> Text)
  toJSON = toJSON . (unsafeCoerce :: Map MyText v -> Map Text v)

instance FromJSON v => FromJSON (Map MyText v) where 
  -- parseJSON x = fmap (M.mapKeys (coerce :: Text -> MyText)) (parseJSON x)
  parseJSON x = (unsafeCoerce :: Parser (Map Text v) -> Parser (Map MyText v)) (parseJSON x)

data Bar = Bar deriving (Eq, Ord, Generic)
instance ToJSON Bar
instance FromJSON Bar

data Foo = Foo (Map MyText Bar) deriving (Generic)
instance ToJSON Foo 
instance FromJSON Foo

newtype Foo2 = Foo2 (Map MyText Bar) deriving (FromJSON, ToJSON)
```